# A black window pops up Unable to copy files unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10

Hi i am trying to install unity3d software on my Windows10 pc. everything downloaded and installed smoothly. but when unity starts its giving the fallowing error [image: error]

and after i click many times on "Try Again" Button a blank window will be poped and unity is not starting. [image]

I have tried to delete the file "unity-editor-home.0.0.13.tgz" but it says permission denied.I have tried reinstalling 3 times but i am having same problem

Comment: Right click Unity and run as an Administrator. Tell me what happens..

Comment: Still its giving the same error "Copying file failed"

Comment: Do you have any anti-virus software running on your computer or even installed?

Comment: Yes i have bitdefender anti-virus software running on my pc

Comment: If you checked **"Linux Build Support**" during installation then follow the answer provided by Soviut. If you didn't then Disable your Anit-virus and try it again.

Comment: I uninstalled my antivirus and reinstalled unity still i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

You've got Linux Build Support checked in the installer. That's why it's copying a tgz (tarball gzip) file. It's giving you access denied errors because it's trying to copy a file to protected user folders. There are two solutions...

If you need Linux Build support (you're planning to distribute your game on Linux):

- Right click the installer > Run As Administrator
- Enter password

If you don't need Linux Build support:

- Uncheck `Linux Build Support` in the installer

[image]

More on this topic can be found [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity3d-5-3-not-working.372682/)

Comment: I am sure that i have not checked "Linux Build Support" while installing the software .Well i will try uninstalling my anti-virus and update u with results thank you.